# < > characters in DOI causing formatting issues

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle, better-bibtex

When using a DOI which contains unusual characters (<, >, etc), which would need to be input into latex in math mode to be properly formatted. The issue is that doing that within the .bib file would then break the associated link. The below example is a version that works for the link to work, but the formatting does not:

[image]

MWV is attached with two versions of the .bib input, one with characters enclosed in $ (which does not work for the link), or one for the unenclosed characters, which formats with upside down ! etc.

I opened a bug case (https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/2644#issuecomment-1709710696) with the better bibtex providers (as my .bib file is being produced through that), but have had no success.

main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                              % BiBTeX style
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\citep{Apel1985}
\cite{Apel19852}
\bibliographystyle{jfm}
\bibliography{BIB}

\end{document}
```

BIB.bib

```
@article{Apel1985,
  title = {The {{Sulu Sea Internal Soliton Experiment}}},
  author = {Apel, John R. and Holbrook, James R. and Liu, Antony K. and Tsai, John J.},
  year = {1985},
  month = dec,
  journal = {Journal of Physical Oceanography},
  volume = {15},
  number = {12},
  pages = {1625--1651},
  publisher = {{American Meteorological Society}},
  issn = {0022-3670, 1520-0485},
  doi = {10.1175/1520-0485(1985)015<1625:TSSISE>2.0.CO;2},
  url = {https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/phoc/15/12/1520-0485_1985_015_1625_tssise_2_0_co_2.xml},
  urldate = {2023-06-22},
  abstract = {Abstract},
  chapter = {Journal of Physical Oceanography},
  langid = {english}
}
@article{Apel19852,
  title = {The {{Sulu Sea Internal Soliton Experiment}}},
  author = {Apel, John R. and Holbrook, James R. and Liu, Antony K. and Tsai, John J.},
  year = {1985},
  month = dec,
  journal = {Journal of Physical Oceanography},
  volume = {15},
  number = {12},
  pages = {1625--1651},
  publisher = {{American Meteorological Society}},
  issn = {0022-3670, 1520-0485},
  doi = {10.1175/1520-0485(1985)015$<$1625:TSSISE$>$2.0.CO;2},
  url = {https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/phoc/15/12/1520-0485_1985_015_1625_tssise_2_0_co_2.xml},
  urldate = {2023-06-22},
  abstract = {Abstract },
  chapter = {Journal of Physical Oceanography},
  langid = {english}
}
```

jfm.bst

```
ENTRY
   { address
     author
     booktitle
     chapter
     edition
     editor
     howpublished
     institution
     journal
     key
     month
     note
     number
     organization
     pages
     publisher
     school
     series
     title
     type
     volume
     year
     eprint
     doi
   }
   {}
   { label extra.label sort.label short.list }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
   #1 'mid.sentence :=
   #2 'after.sentence :=
   #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
   output.state mid.sentence =
     { ", " * write$ }
     { output.state after.block =
         { add.period$ write$
           newline$
           "\newblock " write$
         }
         { output.state before.all =
             'write$
             { add.period$ " " * write$ }
           if$
         }
       if$
       mid.sentence 'output.state :=
     }
   if$
   s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     'pop$
     'output.nonnull
   if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
   duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
     'output.nonnull
   if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
   write$
   newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
     'skip$
     { after.block 'output.state := }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
     'skip$
     { output.state before.all =
         'skip$
         { after.sentence 'output.state := }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
   add.blank
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
     { #1 }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
     { pop$ #0 }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
     'skip$
   if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
   swap$ empty$
   and
     'skip$
     'new.block
   if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
   if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "{\em " swap$ * "\/}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@author}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "\au{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@editor}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "\ed{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@year}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \yr{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@atitle}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \at{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}
FUNCTION {cmd@jtitle}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \jt{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}
FUNCTION {cmd@bktitle}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \bt{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@seriestitle}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \st{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@bvolume}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \bvol{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@volume}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \vol{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@pages}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \pg{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@publisher}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \publ{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@arxiv}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \arxiv{arXiv: " swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {cmd@org}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { " \org{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}


FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {scaps}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }

  % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
  % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
  % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edn." }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "PhD thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.first}
{ "1st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.second}
{ "2nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.third}
{ "3rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fourth}
{ "4th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fifth}
{ "5th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.st}
{ "st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nd}
{ "nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.rd}
{ "rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.th}
{ "th" }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}

MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

FUNCTION {eng.ord}
{ duplicate$ "1" swap$ *
   #-2 #1 substring$ "1" =
      { bbl.th * }
      { duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$
        duplicate$ "1" =
          { pop$ bbl.st * }
          { duplicate$ "2" =
              { pop$ bbl.nd * }
              { "3" =
                  { bbl.rd * }
                  { bbl.th * }
                if$
              }
            if$
           }
        if$
      }
    if$
}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
  {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr
       "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ cmd@author 't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         {
           namesleft #1 >
             { ", " * t * }
             {
               t "others" =
                 { " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
                 { " \& " * t * }
               if$
             }
           if$
         }
         't
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
     }
   while$
}

FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{ 's :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr
       "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
       format.name$ 't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         {
           namesleft #1 >
             { ", " * t * }
             {
               t "others" =
                 { " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
                 { " \& " * t * }
               if$
             }
           if$
         }
         't
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
     }
   while$
}

FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
     { key field.or.null }
     { "" }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
     { "" }
     {
      author format.names scaps 
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
     { "" }
     {
       editor format.names scaps
       editor num.names$ #1 >
         { ", " * bbl.editors * }
         { ", " * bbl.editor * }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.editors}
{ editor empty$
     { "" }
     { editor format.names.ed cmd@editor
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.note}
{ note empty$
     { "" }
     { note #1 #1 substring$
       duplicate$ "{" =
         'skip$
         { output.state mid.sentence =
           { "l" }
           { "u" }
         if$
         change.case$
         }
       if$
       note #2 global.max$ substring$ *
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
     { "" }
     { title "t" change.case$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr
       "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         {
           namesleft #1 >
             { ", " * t * }
             {
               t "others" =
                 { " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
                 { " \& " * t * }
               if$
             }
           if$
         }
         't
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
     }
   while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
     { editor empty$
         { key empty$
             { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
             'key
           if$
         }
         { editor format.full.names }
       if$
     }
     { author format.full.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
     { key empty$
          { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
           'key
       if$
     }
     { author format.full.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
     { key empty$
          { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
           'key
       if$
     }
     { editor format.full.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
   type$ "inbook" =
   or
     'author.editor.key.full
     { type$ "proceedings" =
         'editor.key.full
         'author.key.full
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
   "\bibitem[" write$
   label write$
   ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
      { pop$ }
      { * }
    if$
   "]{" * write$
   cite$ write$
   "}" write$
   newline$
   ""
   before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
   ""
     { t empty$ not }
     { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
         { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
             { "--" *
               t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
             }
             {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                 { "-" *
                   t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                 }
               while$
             }
           if$
         }
         { t #1 #1 substring$ *
           t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
         }
       if$
     }
   while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
   " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
     { "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
        pop$ "????" }
     'skip$
   if$
   extra.label *
   before.all 'output.state :=
   "" swap$ * cmd@year
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
     { "~" }
     { " " }
   if$
   swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
     'pop$
     { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
% Changed (SGLS)
% Notes swap$ fudge
{ volume empty$
     { "" }
     { series empty$
        { "" }
        { series cmd@seriestitle }
      if$
      swap$ bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.connect output cmd@volume
     }
   if$
}
%{ volume empty$
%    { "" }
%    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.connect
%      series empty$
%        'skip$
%        { bbl.of space.word * series emphasize * }
%      if$
%      "volume and number" number either.or.check
%    }
%  if$
%}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
% Changed (SGLS)
{
  volume empty$
     { series empty$
         { ""
           number empty$
             'skip$
             { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
           if$
         }
         { series emphasize " " * number *}
       if$
     }
     { "" }
   if$
}
%{ volume empty$
%    { number empty$
%        { series field.or.null }
%        { output.state mid.sentence =
%            { bbl.number }
%            { bbl.number capitalize }
%          if$
%          number tie.or.space.connect
%          series empty$
%            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
%            { bbl.in space.word * series * }
%          if$
%        }
%      if$
%    }
%    { "" }
%  if$
%}

FUNCTION {is.num}
{ chr.to.int$
   duplicate$ "0" chr.to.int$ < not
   swap$ "9" chr.to.int$ > not and
}

FUNCTION {extract.num}
{ duplicate$ 't :=
   "" 's :=
   { t empty$ not }
   { t #1 #1 substring$
     t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
     duplicate$ is.num
       { s swap$ * 's := }
       { pop$ "" 't := }
     if$
   }
   while$
   s empty$
     'skip$
     { pop$ s }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {convert.edition}
{ edition extract.num "l" change.case$ 's :=
   s "first" = s "1" = or
     { bbl.first 't := }
     { s "second" = s "2" = or
         { bbl.second 't := }
         { s "third" = s "3" = or
             { bbl.third 't := }
             { s "fourth" = s "4" = or
                 { bbl.fourth 't := }
                 { s "fifth" = s "5" = or
                     { bbl.fifth 't := }
                     { s #1 #1 substring$ is.num
                         { s eng.ord 't := }
                         { edition 't := }
                       if$
                     }
                   if$
                 }
               if$
             }
           if$
         }
       if$
     }
   if$
   t
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
     { "" }
     { output.state mid.sentence =
         { convert.edition "l" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
         { convert.edition "t" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
   #0 'multiresult :=
     { multiresult not
       t empty$ not
       and
     }
     { t #1 #1 substring$
       duplicate$ "-" =
       swap$ duplicate$ "," =
       swap$ "+" =
       or or
         { #1 'multiresult := }
         { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
       if$
     }
   while$
   multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
     { "" }
     { pages multi.page.check
         { bbl.pages pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
         { bbl.page pages tie.or.space.connect }
       if$
       cmd@pages
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{
   pages empty$
     'skip$
     { duplicate$ empty$
         { pop$ format.pages }
         { ", " * pages n.dashify cmd@pages * }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
%   bolden 
   cmd@bvolume
   number empty$
     'skip$
     {
       "~(" number * ")" * *
       volume empty$
         { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
         'skip$
       if$
     }
   if$
   format.journal.pages
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
     'format.pages
     { type empty$
         { bbl.chapter }
         { type "l" change.case$ }
       if$
       chapter tie.or.space.connect
       pages empty$
         'skip$
         { ", " * format.pages * }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
% Changed to get edition after booktitle (SGLS)
% Notes swap$ fudge
{ booktitle empty$
     { "" }
     { word.in booktitle emphasize *
       edition empty$
    'skip$
         { swap$ format.edition output }
       if$
       editor empty$
         { "" * }
         {" (" * 
           editor num.names$ #1 >
             { bbl.editors }
             { bbl.editor }
           if$
           *
           " " *
           format.in.editors * 
           ")" *
         }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
     'skip$
     { pop$
       type "t" change.case$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
     { bbl.techrep emphasize }
     'type
   if$
   number empty$
     { "t" change.case$ }
     { number tie.or.space.connect }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
   word.in
   " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
     { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
       word.in
     }
     { bbl.volume capitalize
       volume tie.or.space.connect
       bbl.of space.word *
     }
   if$
   " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
   word.in
   " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.publisher}
{ publisher empty$
     { "empty publisher in " cite$ * warning$ }
     'skip$
   if$
   ""
   address empty$ publisher empty$ and
     'skip$
     {
       address empty$
         'skip$
         { address * }
       if$
       publisher empty$
         'skip$
         { address empty$
             'skip$
             { ": " * }
           if$
           publisher *
         }
       if$
       cmd@publisher
     }
   if$
   output
}

FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
     { "" }
     { ", " * eprint cmd@arxiv * ""}
   if$
}
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{https://doi.org/" * doi * "}" * output
  enclose.check
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
   author format.key output
   format.date "year" output.check
   date.block
   format.title "title" output.check  cmd@atitle
   new.sentence
   crossref missing$
     { journal cmd@jtitle
%       emphasize
       "journal" output.check
       add.blank
       format.vol.num.pages output
     }
     { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
     }
   if$
   doi empty$
        'skip$
    { % Clear the stack
      duplicate$ empty$
        'skip$
        { output.new.block }
      if$
      format.doi
    }
   if$
   format.note output
   format.eprint output
   fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
   "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
   'len :=
   s #1 len substring$ =
     { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
     's
   if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
   s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
   s num.names$ duplicate$
   #2 >
     { pop$ " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
     { #2 <
         'skip$
         { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
             { " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
             { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
           if$
         }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
     { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
         'key
       if$
     }
     { author format.lab.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
     { editor empty$
         { key empty$
             { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
             'key
           if$
         }
         { editor format.lab.names }
       if$
     }
     { author format.lab.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
     { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
         'key
       if$
     }
     { editor format.lab.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
   type$ "inbook" =
   or
     'author.editor.key.label
     { type$ "proceedings" =
         'editor.key.label
         'author.key.label
       if$
     }
   if$
   'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
   short.list
   "("
   *
   year duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "????" }
      'skip$
   if$
   *
   'label :=
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
   #1 'nameptr :=
   ""
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr
       "{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
       format.name$ 't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         {
           "   "  *
           namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
             { "zzzzz" * }
             { t sortify * }
           if$
         }
         { t sortify * }
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
     }
   while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
   "A " #2
     "An " #3
       "The " #4 t chop.word
     chop.word
   chop.word
   sortify
   #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
     { key empty$
         { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
           ""
         }
         { key sortify }
       if$
     }
     { author sort.format.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
     { editor empty$
         { key empty$
             { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
               ""
             }
             { key sortify }
           if$
         }
         { editor sort.format.names }
       if$
     }
     { author sort.format.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
     { key empty$
         { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
           ""
         }
         { key sortify }
       if$
     }
     { editor sort.format.names }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
   label sortify
   "    "
   *
   type$ "book" =
   type$ "inbook" =
   or
     'author.editor.sort
     { type$ "proceedings" =
         'editor.sort
         'author.sort
       if$
     }
   if$
   #1 entry.max$ substring$
   'sort.label :=
   sort.label
   *
   "    "
   *
   title field.or.null
   sort.format.title
   *
   #1 entry.max$ substring$
   'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { last.extra.num number.label }

FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
   "" 'next.extra :=
   #0 'last.extra.num :=
   #0 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
     { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
       last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
     }
     { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
       "" 'extra.label :=
       label 'last.label :=
     }
   if$
   number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
     { "a" 'extra.label := }
     'skip$
   if$
   extra.label 'next.extra :=
   extra.label
   emphasize
   duplicate$ empty$
     'skip$
     { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
   if$
   'extra.label :=
   label extra.label * 'label :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}

FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
   "    "
   *
   year field.or.null sortify
   *
   "    "
   *
   title field.or.null
   sort.format.title
   *
   #1 entry.max$ substring$
   'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {bib.sort.order}

SORT

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
     'skip$
     { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
   if$
   "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
   write$ newline$
"\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi"
  write$ newline$
 "\def\au#1{#1} \def\ed#1{#1} \def\yr#1{#1}\def\at#1{#1}\def\jt#1{\textit{#1}} \def\bt#1{#1}\def\bvol#1{\textbf{#1}} \def\vol#1{#1} \def\pg#1{#1} \def\publ#1{#1}\def\arxiv#1{#1}\def\org#1{#1}\def\st#1{\textit{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
   "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
%%
%% End of file `jfmraw.bst'.
```

Comment: Try executing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.